# Collection Data manipulation Blue Prism: Calculation stage - and split into two collections based on the result

Tags: c#, vb.net, blueprism, rpa

I am currently working on a Collection that has the data of a reconciliation Excel report (accounting). Since there are apprx 1500 rows, looping through the collection takes quite some time.

I'd rather do a code stage that does the calculation, mainly looking to see if there is a difference between two of the rows. All The rows with a difference between the two lines should be exported to a new collection.
Has anybody done anything similar either in C# or VB.script?

[Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtZo7.png)

Comment: 1,500 rows isn't really a lot of data from a Blue Prism perspective - are you sure your current Blue Prism process is optimized fully? Are you running in the fastest Debug mode or from the Control Room?

Comment: Well, that is the first loop in the process, there are quite a few more as several reports need to be reconciled. Was just wondering if anybody had done similar stages using code to gather the differences rather than looping

Comment: I'm not quite sure what do you mean by "difference between two lines". Two lines anywhere in the data? Two adjacent lines? Can you post sample data to show what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi Marek.
there are two lines, one for the bank account and another for what is booked in the books. The current calculation stage has the different between the two rows.

Comment: How do you know that the two lines go together? Are they next to each other or do they have a common ID column? Is it always two matching rows or can there be just one or more than two? Again, a picture would be helpful :)

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you are really going on about. I've done quite a few different things involving many rows myself, but I don't like VB at all and prefer taking the data to SQL for processing.

Comment: I'll try and be more precise.

1. I have added a snip of one of the collections being used in my first post, the two relevant rows are marked yellow.
- The names of the two relevant rows are static on all the reports. The only difference is the figures. 
- Every month the difference between the rows (ub_hovedbok and ub_bank) is calculated. 

2. In cases where the are differences - further action is taken so the relevant rows has to be exported to a new collection

3. In cases where there is none, the lines with no differences is exported to another collection and saved as a PDF.

Comment: My question is, has anybody done something similar in Blue Prism using the code stage?

Comment: I think you got everyone confused by talking about rows while you actually mean columns

Comment: Always confuse them in english *Yes, i mean columns*

Comment: Yes this is easy to do, and there are many ways to do this in code. Different biases/skillsets etc will have their own preferred way. You mention PDF export. How are you currently doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the object `Utility - Collection Manipulation` and the action `Filter Collection`.

As an input collection use the collection you retrieved from the Excel file and as a filter express use this:

```
"[ub_hovedbok] <> [ub_bank]"
```

This will output a new collection with rows only with values different in those two columns.

Alternatively, you could do this with direct OLEDB connection to the Excel file.

Comment: Note that OLEDB doesn't work anymore in MS Office 2016/365. The user would have to remove MS Access of that version and install back MS Access 2013, but I don't see that as a viable option because updates might be pushed from an uncontrollable source (and just adds a lot of more hassle to be honest).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know that. Why is that? Are the drivers missing in the standard Office installation?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure myself, seems like MS did not include a library and might be using something different. I haven't been able to find a workaround while still using OLEDB even on the BluePrism forums, so I've been using SQL since I needed a solution fast (several live bots were affected by it). Actually, the code stage I've been using uses `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` for the provider parameter of the connection. Maybe I don't know where to repoint it, but changing 12 to a new version didn't work.